# use of weather-js module returns unexpected identifier error

Tags: javascript, weather-api

I'm using the weather-js npm module. I received an error related to the require statement ('require is not defined') so I'm using the import statement but now I'm receiving an 'unexpected identifier' error. How would I solve this?
[image: This is the where the error occurs]
JS

```
import weather from 'weather-js'

weather.find({search: 'Manchester', degreeType: 'C'}, function(err, result) {
    if(err) console.log(err);

    console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
  });
```

Comment: Can you share the error stack trace? Also, how are you running the code? Through babel? As a module in node? In the browser?

Comment: @Khauri I'm not using webpack or babel. I'm running the code in the developer tools in my browser. The code prints fine in the terminal but not in the dev tools in the browser.

Comment: In a browser you'd have to load `weather-js` in a script tag before using it. But it's worth mentioning that `weather-js` seems like it was developed to run only within a node environment and would not work in a browser environment. I'd also like to point out that the module you're trying to use hasn't been updated in 2 years and the github page for it has been archived, so it probably won't work anyway.

Comment: @Khauri I see, thank you for the information! I'll find another weather api.